# redirectMatch 301 not working (htaccess)

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

this is a htaccess issue I have and I can't solve.
I've just moved my site from /2014 to / (root directory) and I want to redirect everything from 2014 to root directory just in case.
The last parameter is another thing, it's working but I include it here just in the case it may be interfering the redirectMatch 301.

```
#Active RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine on

# 301 Redirect Entire Directory 2014 to root
redirectMatch 301 ^2014(.*)$ http://www.rosariodesign.com$1

#Friendly URL for /registro.php -> /registro
RewriteRule ^registro/?$ registro.php
```

What may be the problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you getting some kind of error? What does your logs say?

Comment: it just don't redirect, my console says nothing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this code in `/2014/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /2014/

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.rosariodesign.com/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```